# Clarification on Android documentation : Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

The documentation is well defined on Fragments in Android developer site but I have doubt about one particular life cycle method in Fragments

> http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
>
> `onAttach()` Called when **the fragment has been associated with the
>   activity** (the Activity is passed in here).

What does this association internally does ?

Further I checked here

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java?av=f

> Default constructor. Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so
>   it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is
>   strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors
>   with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the
>   fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the
>   caller with setArguments(android.os.Bundle) and later retrieved by the
>   Fragment with getArguments(). Applications should generally not
>   implement a constructor. The first place application code an run where
>   the fragment is ready to be used is in onAttach(android.app.Activity),
>   the point **where the fragment is actually associated with its activity**.
>   Some applications may also want to implement
>   onInflate(android.app.Activity,android.util.AttributeSet,android.os.Bundle)
>   to retrieve attributes from a layout resource, though should take care
>   here because this happens for the fragment is attached to its
>       }

but again the same term but no exact explanation.

Comment: you can add the line to your grepcode-sample, so you don't have to search for ages

Answer (score 2):

A `Fragment` is nothing but a component which can be attached to an `Activity`, or detached from an Activity. With other words, the Activity is something like a host for the Fragment.

In order to know when the Fragment is attached, or detached from the host activity, it provides 2 callback methods:
`onAttach()` - called by the system when adding the fragment to the activity
`onDetach()` - called by the system when removing the fragment from activity

When they say "the fragment has been associated with the activity", it means that the fragment was added to the activity, and it means that from here on you can call `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is  **What does this association internally does ?**

And I found below code in FrgmentManager class that what is I was looking for,
This show exactly how following **ASSOCIATION** is made,

> the fragment has been associated with the activity

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java

```
                f.mActivity = mActivity;
                f.mParentFragment = mParent;
                f.mFragmentManager = mParent != null
                        ? mParent.mChildFragmentManager : mActivity.mFragments;
                f.mCalled = false;
                f.onAttach(mActivity);
```

above code does the assignment of Fragment's associated Activty and then call the onAttach(..)